# Example where the free $R$-module $R$ does not induce a free abelian group with the same basis

Tags: group-theory, modules, free-modules

For some reason, I'm stuck in the notion that taking $R$ as a free $R$-module, with basis $B$, induces a free abelian group on the additive group in $R$ with basis $B$ (i.e. the abelian group in the ring $R$ would have the same basis $B$).

To convince myself otherwise, I'm looking for a counter-example. I can sort of see why it might not be true - intuitively, the coefficients used to describe elements as combinations of basis elements are not the same (one has coefficients in $R$ while the other has integer coefficients), but, being stuck with the usual example of $R=\mathbb{Z}$ (for which it *does* hold true), I'm unable to find a counter example. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more precise?  You say "the abelian group in the ring $R$ would have the same basis $B$" but *which* abelian group do you mean?

Comment: @EricWofsey There's only one in a ring, no? The additive one. Added it to my question too.

Comment: @EricWofsey For example, when $R=\mathbb{Z}$, the free module with basis $B$ is the free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ with basis $B$. My problem is I seem to keep thinking this holds true for any $R$, hence the need for a counter example that I can keep in mind.

Comment: This is false for literally *any* ring other than $R=\mathbb{Z}$.  What examples have you tried?

Comment: @EricWofsey OK I see it now with $\mathbb{R}$. My problem was that, since I have just learned about these topics, I didn't have many examples in mind besides $\mathbb{Z}$. Will post my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Another familiar counterexample is when $R$ is a finite field, in which case a free $R$-module is additively  an elementary abelian $p$-group where $p = {\rm char}(R)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since any vector space is a free module over itself, in particular so is $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $B=\{1\}$.

$\mathbb{R}$ is not free abelian with basis $\{1\}$ since, e.g. there is no integer $n$ such that $\pi = n$.